# How can I convert a queue message to a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json, type-conversion, rabbitmq, queue

I am using a queue in Node.js (with Express) to retrieve a buffer (array with bytes). This buffer contains a JSON object (in String form). When trying to convert the string back to JSON, Javascript no longer recognizes the JSON.

I have tried to convert the queue message content to a String, this works. When I try to parse this String to JSON using `JSON.parse()`, it throws a SyntaxError because quotes are missing. When I first use JSON.Stringify() and then use JSON.Parse(), it seems to work but when I try to display a JSON field (like booking.FlightID), it returns 'undefined'.

This is what the parsed JSON looks like:

```
{ _id: 5d0bf0a7086a1a239cd9842d,
  Passenger:
   [ { _id: 5d0bf0a7086a1a239cd9842f,
       FirstName: 'Alice',
       LastName: 'Black',
       Age: '19',
       Gender: 'Male',
       BaggageKG: 20 },
     { _id: 5d0bf0a7086a1a239cd9842e,
       FirstName: 'Dave',
       LastName: 'White',
       Age: '29',
       Gender: 'Female',
       BaggageKG: 45 } ],
  FlightID: 21,
  Email: 'THIS IS A TEST @mail.com',
  __v: 0 }
```

And this is my method of parsing:

```
  var booking = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(msg.content.toString()));
```

Where msg.content is a Buffer.

I need to be able to read the individual JSON field, for example `Booking.FlightID`.

To clarify; I am retrieving a buffer of a String with JSON data. I want to parse it back to actual JSON.

---

This is the content which is sent in to the queue:

```
var booking = new Booking();
var msg = booking.toString();
```

(console.log(msg) shows the following):

```
{ _id: 5d0bf3cf870dba3ed8a5808f,
  Passenger:
   [ { _id: 5d0bf3cf870dba3ed8a58091,
       FirstName: 'Alice',
       LastName: 'Black',
       Age: '19',
       Gender: 'Male',
       BaggageKG: 20 },
     { _id: 5d0bf3cf870dba3ed8a58090,
       FirstName: 'Dave',
       LastName: 'White',
       Age: '29',
       Gender: 'Female',
       BaggageKG: 45 } ],
  FlightID: 21,
  Email: 'THIS IS A TEST @mail.com' }
```

---

I changed the way I add the message to the buffer. Instead of `object.toString()`, I now use `JSON.Stringify(object)`. Now, when I retrieve and parse the message from the queue, this is the content:

```
{"_id":"5d0bf6b7211c3351fca6e071","Passenger":[{"_id":"5d0bf6b7211c3351fca6e073","FirstName":"Alice","LastName":"Black","Age":"19","Gender":"Male","BaggageKG":20},{"_id":"5d0bf6b7211c3351fca6e072","FirstName":"Dave","LastName":"White","Age":"29","Gender":"Female","BaggageKG":45}],"FlightID":21,"Email":"THIS IS A TEST @mail.com","__v":0}
```

The formatting is not very pretty but the quotes seem to be alright now.
This seems to have solved the issue.

Comment: The strange thing to me is that the parsed JSON looks fine to me, but when I try to read the fields, they are undefined.

Comment: Why are you stringifying and then parsing? Why not skip both steps?

Comment: JSON is always a string; there is no such thing as a "JSON object".  It's a serialization format. If you're getting a string in that format, just `JSON.parse()` it without stringifying it first.

Comment: @Pointy thanks for your response, I don't really know, I'm new to Javascript and JSON, I tried this and it worked. Are you saying that msg.content.toString() would return a valid JSON object?

Comment: @Pointy if I don't stringify it, it returns a SyntaxError, I thinks because quotes are missing.

Comment: I don't know what your message content looks like. If it doesn't have proper quotes, then it is not JSON. JSON insists on quotes (double quotes in fact). It would help to clarify what you're asking if you'd post the actual original content.

Comment: @Pointy I posted the content that is sent to the queue, it does not seem to have proper quotes which is strange. Could this be the problem? And if so, why does this happen?

Comment: It looks like you're getting a complete, already-parsed object back. It's really hard to tell what's going on from what you posted.

Comment: Whatever component is creating this Buffer is not inserting valid json.  you need to change that part to insert valid json.

Comment: @James you were right, thank you.